# What database to choose for the hierarchical content with relations?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, rdbms, nosql

I want to have a reviews-like website, but not only with reviews, other types of content as well. The design of the website combines both hierarchical structure (each content object/record/entity has a parent - kind of container), and relations - each content object/record/entity has a number of related other objects:

- an author of the content (i.e. user)
- related comments (with their own relations, particularly authors)
- item being reviewed as a separate record in DB
- images from the gallery

One of the most important things is performance. Relations used to be inefficient in the NoSQL, as I've read on the net and already tried out with other projects. On the other hand, the general design, apart from the relations mentioned, has an obvious content repository like structure, which is the exact reflection of hierarchical arrangement of objects (documents, articles, reviews) websites are designed. Also, I really like the loose structure of the records in NoSQL. Yet, I don't care about (nor use) things like versioning and other things related to NoSQL.

So I want to combine both wordls: hierarchical and relational within one project, or actually, its model. Apart from it, I want the project to be **restful**, so that a mobile apps could use the same content available through the API. Another requirement is that the content should be **searchable**.

**What type of storage would you choose for a project like this?**

Comment: The downvotes are unfair here. People probably even didn't read the question! I provided the exact use case I have, hence it's not too broad nor off topic.

Comment: It is a broad architecture question and touches on many areas (data structure, REST API, search) but I think it is still a valid question. It is very unhelpful to down-vote without giving a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the Graph DBs. Here's why I rejected the other ones:

- I don't want to use NoSQL (Documents), since relations are hard to maintain and often require extra code infrastructure (often custom) to handle them, see e.g. [Diaspora NoSQL problems](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2013/11/11/why-you-should-never-use-mongodb/)
- I don't want to use RDBMS, since the structure based DBs impose well known limitations and doesn't reflect the domain
- I rejected the key-value and big table DBs as they have very specific use cases

Graph Databases have been used in number of content-oriented projects, and appeared to be doing the job surprisingly well.

Comment: Out of curiousity, can you specify which specific graph database you chose?

Comment: StackOverflow sometimes astonishes me. It seems that for no reason I got -6 votes so far, but people are still interested in the answer. I decided to go with Neo4j. Why do you ask?

Comment: It may be more helpful to update your answer to say that, in case someone in future is in a similar situation. I was just curious which you chose, but I haven't used Neo4j though. I still stand by my recommendation but best of luck to you with it!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily model a hierarchical data structure in SQL with the following (using PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id INTEGER,
    parent INTEGER,
    content VARCHAR(1024)
)
```

Where `parent` refers to the `id` of the parent comment.

If you are after a NoSQL database that exposes a RESTful interface, you could consider [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/).
You can then replicate CouchDB to [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) for more robust searching.

But if your data is relational then I would very much recommend you consider a SQL database like [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) first.

Comment: So you don't recommend using NoSQL DBs at all, when relations are also important? Arrays in PGSQL seems to be a nice feature (which I frequently used in NoSQL), yet I wonder how well they do in practice in the RDBMS world - can you elaborate on it a bit, or is it out of the scope of your experience?

Comment: Hard to say without a specific use case, but I would encourage exploring SQL first, and seeing where the limits are. My NoSQL experience (document, key store) has shown it is better when updates to items are broad, like an entire JSON document, rather than many, specific parts of that document. Happy to look at other questions, and please mark this as the answer if I have helped.

Comment: I guess, you mean embedded kind of "relation" in the NoSQL, when speaking of broad updates? BTW I described exactly my use case.

Comment: By use case I should have said specific code, I was just wondering if there was something unmentioned that makes SQL unfit.
By broad updates I mean like updating an article and all the comments at once, which would be harder if the data is spread across multiple tables.
You could consider the JSON field type in PostgreSQL to get a flexible data structure and still have relations between those fields.
You could also use a database migration library to help if you want to change the structure later.

Comment: Thx. I considered JSON field type in PostreSQL, which I haven't used so far, but I decided to not use it. JSON field types in RDBMS are something unusual, which forces you to the particular solution. Also, it's relatively a new addition, which is potentially risky and unmature. To top it, there are available dedicated solutions which have been designed in mind to handle loose structures, like JSON field types.

Comment: Admittedly I haven't used them, but I have seen positive chat after adoption. The syntax seems useful but it really depends on your usage. Any system will push you into their particular solution, you just need to pick the best suited and supported.

Comment: Yes, I think so that the best supported (which also means, mature) solution is the most recommended option. From my experience, not too mature things, even like ReactJS, tend to be risky.